# Use QtWebKit only for parsing HTML?

Tags: c++, qt, html-parsing, qtwebkit

Is it possible to use `QtWebKit's` HTML traversing functions *only*? I mean, without using **any** widgets it provides (like QWebView or QWebPage) ... say you got an `HTML` page in a QString and wish to parse it like you would with `QWebElement`.

This would be rather useful if you have to parse HTML in threads, where you can't create widgets and using signals and slots would excessively complicate the code.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use QtWebKit for this purpose. Use classes from `WebCore` namespace. Need example?

Comment: I would also appreciate it, artyom.stv